# Python. List of list check for adjacent spaces

Tags: python, list

Hi I have been trying to build a Tic Tac Toe game in Python, and therefore I am checking a list of lists for adjacent symbols. I know the code is not elegant. But my main concern is that this routine is giving me random results. Can you guys see why?

```
def winx(self):
    if self.current_table [0][0] and self.current_table [0][1] and self.current_table[0][2]== "x":
        print "Good Boy, you won"
        self.winner=1
    elif self.current_table [1][0] and self.current_table [1][1] and self.current_table[1][2]== "x":
        print "Good Boy, you won"
        self.winner=1
    elif self.current_table [2][0] and self.current_table [2][1] and self.current_table[2][2]== "x":
        print "Good Boy, you won"
        self.winner=1
    elif self.current_table [0][0] and self.current_table [1][0] and self.current_table[2][0]== "x":
        print "Good Boy, you won"
        self.winner=1
    elif self.current_table [0][1] and self.current_table [1][1] and self.current_table[2][1]== "x":
        print "Good Boy, you won"
        self.winner=1
    elif self.current_table [0][2] and self.current_table [1][2] and self.current_table[2][2]== "x":
        print "Good Boy, you won"
        self.winner=1
    elif self.current_table [0][0] and self.current_table [1][1] and self.current_table[2][2]== "x":
        print "Good Boy, you won"
        self.winner=1
    elif self.current_table [0][2] and self.current_table [1][1] and self.current_table[2][0]== "x":
        print "Good Boy, you won"
        self.winner=1
    else:
        self.winner=None "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put

```
 if a and b and c == 'x'
```

you are checking if a is nonzero and b is nonzero and c is equal to 'x'
(where any nonempty string counts as nonzero)

If you put

```
 if a==b==c=='x'
```

that should tell you if all three variables are equal to 'x'

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the only issue, but you can't group comparison like that:

```
if self.current_table[0][0] \
   and self.current_table[0][1] \
   and self.current_table[0][2]== "x":
#                              ^^^^^^
```

You have to write:

```
if self.current_table[0][0] == "x" \
   and self.current_table [0][1] == "x" \
   and self.current_table[0][2]== "x":
```

Or

```
if self.current_table[0][0] == \
   self.current_table[0][1] == \
   self.current_table[0][2] == "x":
```

Or

```
if (self.current_table[0][0],self.current_table [0][1],self.current_table[0][2]) == ("x","x","x"):
```